# Accept Stripe Webhooks with TLS 1.3 / Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, kubernetes-ingress, tls1.2, tls1.3

I need to listen to Stripe events at a webhook that is deployed on Kubernetes.

The certificate used in the Ingress is using TLS 1.3 but according to Stripe docs, their webhook requests are using TLS 1.2.

Therefore I am getting TLS Errors in the Stripe Webhooks Dashboard.

I am not sure if it is even possible to accept TLS 1.2 requests from a certificate with TLS 1.3 or if I need to add some annotations in the Ingress.

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: could you please provide that errors you're facing and what is your Kubernetes version? If it's possible, provide your deployment files with ingress and your pod

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.